# After validation fails and a form redirects back to itself, why are instance variables empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app, when a certain form fails to save (validation fails) and redirects back to the form I get an error:

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

This form does not display any errors when navigating directly to the new or edit paths.

The error is coming from a select field with a custom `options_from_collection_for_select` method.

```
<%= f.select(:user_ids, options_from_collection_for_select_with_attributes(@users, :id, :name, 'data-attributes', :attributes ), {include_blank:true}, {multiple:true}) %>
```

If I replace the instance variable `@users` with `User.all` then I don't get an error after redirect.

I guess `@users` is empty after the redirect, hence the error. But why? `@users` is defined in the new and edit controllers.

My controller is:

```
def create
  --bunch of stuff
  if @model.save
    --bunch of stuff
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :text => model_url(@model) }
      format.html { redirect_to(@model, :notice => 'Success!.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @model, :status => :created, :location => @model }
    end

  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @model.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I've had the same issue. I guess the actual `edit` method does not get called on redirect. Ive had to re-initialize all instance vars like your `@users` before the redirect

Comment: If validation fails, you should NOT re-direct. Instead, you should simply render the appropriate view (:new if create failed, :edit if update failed)

Comment: thanks @Adnan. I hope I don't need to do that, it's going to get length on complex forms!

Comment: @LarryK, thanks. I am rendering not redirecting. Sorry for the misleading question.

Comment: I usually define a method, (say `pre_requisites`) that contains all the initializations. I then use this method in the `edit` and `new` actions (as they are often the same initializations, and also before I call the render in case of validation failures

Comment: @LarryK yea I meant render too.. sorry about the misleading comment

Comment: Surprisingly common problem without an elegant solution. A private method that gets called in multiple spots, like `pre_requisites` as @Adnan suggested, seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because you don't actually execute the "new" action if it fails. Here's a typical controller structure

```
class PotsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @pot = Pot.new
    @users = User.all
  end

  def create
    @pot = Pot.new(params[:pot])
    if @pot.create
      redirect_to @pot, notice: "Created"
    else
      #****you are here****
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

In the above, if `pot.create` fails, it just renders the new template. What you should do is get your instance variables in that case too

```
  def create
    @pot = Pot.new(params[:pot])
    if @pot.create
      redirect_to @pot, notice: "Created"
    else
      @users = User.all #this is the important line
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks @Jesse, is there a short hand for this? It's going to get complex if I need to define all my instance variables twice on complex forms.

Comment: you can move all the load_instance_variables into a method and call the method in both places. This is pretty standard if you're loading more than 1 instance variable.